# Create Browser control in a popup window without it stealing focus

Tags: winforms, browser, focus, cefsharp

We are building a custom web browser using CefSharp WinForms (version 71.0.2.0) and need to open a popup form containing a browser control.  This popup must not steal focus from any other window the user has open (the current app and any others they are working in) but must pop up in front of any others.

We have successfully managed this in a previous version of the application which used a different Chrome wrapper.

Whatever I try I cannot get it to work.

Using the following:

```
    frm.Visible = false;
    frm.TopMost = false;
    ShowWindow(frm.Handle, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);
    SetWindowPos((int)frm.Handle, HWND_TOPMOST,frm.Left, frm.Top, frm.Width, frm.Height,SWP_NOACTIVATE);
    frm.Visible = true;    //So that Load event happens
```

shows an inactive window if I don't include a browser on it, when I add a browser window and call the above it steals focus.

Comment: Latest version is relative, please specify the exact version. You will be able to control form activation in version 73 for which the first -pre release is due out shortly. See https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/issues/1856/branch-2526-cef-activates-browser-window

Comment: That's excellent news, do you have any info about how this will be implemented in CefSharp?

Comment: See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/issues/1811

Comment: A `pre-release` version of `73` is now on `Nuget.org` see https://www.nuget.org/packages/CefSharp.WinForms/73.1.120-pre01